# how to make prettier not split this code?

Tags: prettier

whenever I use the querySelector element in javascript prettier split the line into multiple lines, how can I prevent that from happening

e.g
what I want:

`document.querySelector('#current--' + activePlayer).textContent = roundScore;`

what prettier do:

```
    document.querySelector(`

        '#current--' + activePlayer

       ).textContent = roundScore;
```

Comment: can you include your prettier config? I'm using default prettier in VS Code and see no auto-formatting similar to your result.

Comment: still not able to reproduce. However, you might try: https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html. I can ignore the "singleQuote" using: `// prettier-ignore`

Comment: `{
    "singleQuote": true, 
    "arrowParens": "avoid",
    "bracketSpacing": false,
    "tabWidth": 4
}`

Comment: also remind you, don't mix too many extensions on formatting code. Please try again with  `Format selection with ... ` command to see the options.

Comment: thanks for the help, I found out that the problem was with the "printWidth" element so I increased it from 80 (default) to 100.